# R: Error: unexpected numeric constant (in names of columns)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an error that I don't understand.

I have downloaded an Excel file with unemploymente rates by country and by year.
Basically, column 1 is Country, column 2 is 1990, column 3 etc...

I am trying to plot an histogram unemployment rate in 2005.
I use this code:

```
qplot(x=2005,y=Country,data=data)
```

But I always have this error:

```
Error: unexpected numeric constant in
```

I have tried to:
- convert all the names in character
- add a "y" before the year
- put brackets

But I still have this error.

```
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "qplot(y=data$2005"
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "qplot(x=y 2005"
```

With brackets, I have this error

```
Error: unexpected '[' in "qplot(x=["
```

Any idea? Many thanks in advance!

Edit:
Dataset:[link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1frieoKODnD9sX3VCZy5c3QAjBXMY-vN7k_I9gR-gcU8/pub?gid=0[link]

I have downloaded it (xlxs format), and changed the name of the first column

```
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
file<-"indicator_t 15-24 unemploy.xlsx"
excel_sheets(file)
data<-read_excel(file)
```

I've tried to plot:

```
qplot(x=2005,y=Total 15-24 unemployment (%),data=data)

Error: unexpected numeric constant in "qplot(x=2005,y=Total 15"
```

I have changed the named of the first column, and added a "y" before the years.

```
names2<-paste("y",names(data[,2:length(data)]))
data2<-c("Country",names2)
colnames(data)<-data2
```

I still have an error:

```
qplot(x=y2005,y=Country,data=data)

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y2005' not found
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems in your code, and you could certainly benefit from reading some basic references on R, such as http://tryr.codeschool.com/

What you are trying to do may be accomplished by

```
qplot ( x = data$"2005" , ylab="Total 15-24 unemployment (%)")
```

Here, the first argument specifies which data should be plotted, and ylab is used to set the y-axis label. Notice that this label must be enclosed by "quotes".

**Edit:**
Note also that "2005" **may or may not** be the name of your column. Check what are your column names with `colnames(data)`.

Regarding the comment below, if the name of the column is actually 2005, you need to quote it as well. If you don't, R will interpret 2005 as a numerical constant:

```
> x$2000
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "x$2000"
> x$"2000"
[1] 1 2 4 6
```

Comment: x = data$"2005" should be x = data$2005

Comment: Yes, it's working! Many thanks. I know that I'm doing mistakes, but I am learning and taking courses (but I have never seen this problem in my classes). Many thanks!